# Workarounds to get Google sign-in functioning with Python 2.6 and pyOpenSSL 0.10-2

Tags: python, python-2.6, pyopenssl, google-signin

I'm trying to get [Google sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library) working using their [Python API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/) but the server I'm on ([4UHosting](https://www.4uhosting.co.uk)) has Python 2.6 and pyOpenSSL 0.10-2 (5-years old).

This means that the API's call to [OpenSSL.crypto.verify()](https://pyopenssl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.verify) fails as it doesn't exist in this version.

I can't install these myself, even `--self` as they require compiler use which I don't have. The admins are reluctant to install any updates that are not vetted. They won't install pyOpenSSL or Python 2.7 locally just for me. I can't find documentation from pyOpenSSL 0.10-2 that would have an equivalent function to verify().

I'm looking for some suggestions as where to head from here.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated,
Cyrille

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ideas:

1. You could directly make your API calls to the Google API Endpoints instead of using the Python client library, for example, the [token info](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/oauth2/m/oauth2/v2/oauth2.tokeninfo) endpoint can be used to verify tokens
2. You could do sign-in operations [client-side](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) and transfer data to your server once a session is attached
3. You could use another language (e.g. [Ruby](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-ruby)) for the sign-in operations

Comment: I will explore these and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: I decided to go with the endpoint: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth